# Url not using php curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to open a https url but it is not working.It works for other https websites but for this it is not working.I don't know the reason why it is happening like that.Below is the code i have written.
Please help.

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $url = "https://sgate.bmwgroup.com/login_common.fcc";
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 200);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);
 curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2)          Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)" );
  $curl_scraped_page= curl_exec($ch);
  if(!$curl_scraped_page)
{
echo "first learn";
}
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
 echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
 }
 echo $curl_scraped_page;
 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```

Comment: What error message are you reciving?

Comment: Clarify what is exactly "not working"

Comment: A blank page opens up.

Comment: Blank page? I'm assuming a 500 error. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: No its not that error atleast.

Comment: Judging by your code it should echo `"first learn"` if the response page is **really** blank (empty). Otherwise it is not blank

Comment: Yeah header response is 200 ok. But i don't know why it is not displaying.

Comment: @user2396181 _But i don't know why it is not displaying_ Apparently because the content of page is generated by Javascript which is neither loaded nor rendered by CURL.

Comment: i have tried each thing.But don't know what to do now.

Comment: @user2396181 What have you exactly tried?

Comment: All the curl constants that used for displaying https websites.

Comment: @user2396181 Curl **cannot display** neither `https` nor `http` websites. It's only for getting raw HTTP response. Displaying it like in browser is entirely your concern, not Curl's.

Answer (score 0):

good news that page is working, bad news that site is using javascript, and while he doesn't get his scripts, the page is not showing. instead of `echo $curl_scraped_page;`
try to use:

```
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($curl_scraped_page));
```

Comment: Yeah but atleast something should display like google or outlook.

Comment: no, because you open it in browser, so it will trat as html, and nothing will display.

Comment: Use this url in some proxy changer website.They are also using curl there it displays correctly

Comment: @Maximilian Prepl How this can help to render javascript output?

Comment: @hindmost this will show that curl is working correctly.

Comment: @user2396181 yes. because, they change even urls from `<script>` tags, so even scripts will be anonymous, and will show what you want. this is more advanced.

Comment: @Maximilian Prepl In order to see this it is enough to select "Source Code" command in the browser. Your answer doesn't provide any solution, so it should be a comment.

Comment: @hindmost yes, it is enough, but, i need more reputation to use comment function :D so solution to help person is to respond here ;)