# Url not diplaying using php curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to display a https url but it is not working.It works for other https websites like facebook,microsoft,google but for this it is not working.I don't know the reason why it is happening like that.Below is the code i have written.
Please help.

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $url = "https://sgate.bmwgroup.com/login_common.fcc";
 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 200);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,TRUE);
 curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2)          Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)" );
  $curl_scraped_page= curl_exec($ch);
  if(!$curl_scraped_page)
{
echo "first learn";
}
if(curl_errno($ch)) {
 echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
 }
 echo $curl_scraped_page;
 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```

Comment: Why you duplicate your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178542/url-not-using-php-curl)? Close this

Comment: Actually first was posted accidently

Comment: @user2396181 then close/delete this.

Comment: You have to close this one since the earlier one already has discussion

Comment: i am new to this stackoverflow.Can you tell me where i hv the option to close this

Comment: Use ctrl + f, type "close"

Comment: Is it a joke.Everyone knows ctrl+F